# How to call a custom thumbnail image size in WordPress when coming from a field?

Tags: wordpress

I've added a function to my theme that allows the user to "upload" an image for a gallery. The field is called "thumbnail" and it returns a url ("http://example.com/wp-content/upload/image.jpg").

My problem is that I have added new thumbnail sizes (add_image_size()), regenerated the photos, but now I'm having issues calling the new image.

**Example:**

- I have an image called: http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/image1.jpg
- I've regenerated an image called http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/image1-150x650.jpg
- When I use, get_field('thumbnail'), it returns the original image. I need it to return the image that has "-150x650.jpg" attached.

I've tried using preg_replace but it doesn't allow for various file names, sizes, and file extensions. How can I call that URL, and add my new image size?

Answer (score 0):

The code you need is provided in the ACF documentation on images:

```
<?php 
$image = get_field( 'image' );
$size = 'full'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)

if( $image ) {
    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );

}
?>
```

See: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image